# What to do when an OP adds comments to their previous Q&A asking for help on their new question?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, comment-flags

A user posted a question and it was answered. On the next day that user posted another question which is not related to their previous question.

After asking the new question, the user posted a comment on their previous question and its answer. The comment read: "**Help me out plzz** *<link to the new question>*".

Since the new comment is not relevant to the original question, can I flag the comment in this case?

Comment: Sounds like he is acting like SO is a forum and that his comment is more likely to be seen than his new Question.  No need to flag it, just ignore it.

Comment: Instead of flagging it, be glad that he asked a new question instead of editing his previous one (chameleon). Personally I find these comments very helpful, as they link the questions and possibly provide background to unclear questions.

Comment: @Bergi: I agree. In case if those two questions does not have any relation, entirely different concept but having common tags. In this case, can i flag?

Comment: @Arulkumar: Yeah, if it's not a follow-up but really just link spam to get views on a entirely different topic, flag as `not constructive`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are correct that it is not relevant to the question or its answers, and is generally used by the OP just to draw attention to a new question from users likely to have the ability to answer it.

What you should do is flag the comment(s) as "no longer needed". Moderators will immediately understand that such comments are noisy and not-constructive, and they will be deleted.

I get these comments occasionally on my old answers, asking me to look into and answer new questions. If you receive a comment on one of your old posts requesting that you look at a new question (probably related to the old one), you are under *no obligation* to do so. You may ignore or flag it.