# Question asks for specific user to answer

Tags: discussion, questions

I sometimes encounter a question that asks for specific user to answer.

Is that OK? I didn't see anywhere that says you shouldn't, but I don't think it's good practice within a community.

Should such a question be flagged or ignored?

Comment: So you see questions like *Hey user xyz what is the answer to this question: ...*?

Comment: Related: [What to do when an OP adds comments to their previous Q&A asking for help on their new question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289365/2451726)

Comment: @Arulkumar Notice in your link it's suggest to flag question and here to remove request

Comment: Somehow I was able to talk myself out of editing "Hey Servy" into the beginning of this question.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Even better if the OP had had that idea they could have edited it in after I answered without even leaving a new revision, making it appear as if it was asked that way from the start.

Comment: @NathanOliver I do see it from time to time, yes.  Not often.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Just edit the question to remove the request for a specific person to answer it from the question.  It's noise that adds nothing to the question.

If the request is in a comment, just flag the comment as not necessary, because it too is just noise.

If it's not *possible* for anyone but that one person to answer the question, due to the nature of the question, then the question should be closed, as that's not a suitable type of question for SO.  If the question is otherwise appropriate and can be given a quality answer by anyone, not just the requested person, then nothing else need be done.

Comment: Key to the last paragraph is "due to the nature of the question" - there are questions that only one or two people can answer simply because they are the only ones with the domain knowledge to answer. These questions are not the same as, say, a question about a design decision made by one person that only they can answer.

Comment: @BoltClock Well, then ask the one or two people directly, not *the whole community* ;)

Comment: @Έρικ Two problems with that. First, that person may not wish to be contacted outside of the site, or you may not have their contact information. Second, even if you do, it means the information is not available to everyone (it's just between the two of you), which runs counter to our core mission here of assembling a library of high-quality answers to programming questions.

Comment: @CodyGray Then they probably don't want to be asked such a question anyways...or they don't want you to know the answer, so best leave it alone.

Comment: That is self-evidently false. Eric Lippert has answered hundreds of questions here whose answers are extremely useful, yet I don't have his contact information and couldn't ask him a programming question directly if I wanted to. I mean, I don't know, maybe he doesn't want *me* to know the answer, but he obviously wants *everyone else* to know the answer. @Έρικ

Comment: @CodyGray His contact information is public.  You could contact him directly if you actually wanted to.  Likewise, when he gets questions asked of him privately that he thinks would be useful to the larger programming community, he posts the answers as blog posts *for the whole world to see* rather than [just] replying to the person that asked the question.  Additionally, those useful quesitons that Eric is answering on SO (rather than, his blog) are questions that *aren't* questions only Eric could answer, they're questions anyone could answer, but Eric simply choose to answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, you could also contact Eric on Twitter, where the question, and its reply, would all be public.

Comment: @Έρικ Κωνσταντόπουλος: But I as the asker don't necessarily *know* that only one or two people know the answer to my question, let alone *who* in order to be able to get in touch with them. The reason I ask a question on Stack Overflow is to get an answer from *someone* who knows the answer - regardless of how many actually do. That's different from wanting a specific individual to answer my question.

Comment: @BoltClock The latter is what is concerned here though as far as I can tell. (btw move this to chat or something?)

Comment: @Έρικ Κωνσταντόπουλος: Yeah, I'm just cautioning readers not to conflate the former with the latter when reviewing questions.

Comment: @Kaiido No, because someone asked a question that anyone could answer by simply doing the research.  It's not a question that only one person is *capable* of answering (not off hand, but *ever*).