# Is it ok to "ping" a user we think can help?

Tags: discussion

I have an issue with MediaWiki I can't resolve, and I can't find a solution online. I've posted a question here, but it's gotten 13 views, and I'm fearing it'll sink into obscurity and I'll be no closer to finding an answer. A few questions similar to mine have been asked (between a year and a few months ago), but none of the solutions posted on them have helped me.

However, there is one user who was active on each related question. He seems to understand my issue in particular, and he solved the problem for most of the other askers. After more searching, I've discovered he is also part of the MediaWiki team.

Is it frowned upon to comment on his answer to one of the previous questions (or one of his comments) saying something like:

> I'm having a similar problem here [question link], but the solutions on this question aren't quite working for me. Would you mind giving it a look if you have a chance and help me see what I'm missing?

Obviously Stack Overflow users aren't here to be my personal assistants. We all volunteer to help, so I'd feel bad seeking out one person's help in particular. However, if this user would be willing to help but simply didn't know my question existed, then Stack Overflow loses a potential Q/A (not just for me, but future users too).

Is it in poor taste to post a comment like the one above?

Comment: Yes, that is very much frowned upon

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289365/what-to-do-when-an-op-adds-comments-to-their-previous-qa-asking-for-help-on-the

Comment: The closing "duplicate" doesn't apply, nor does the link in the comment above. Both talk about  other questions being *unrelated* to the one the OP wants to draw the expert's attention to. And not just any expert but such that had already frequently  participated in related previous questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is poor form. Just think of how many pings the top users in each tag would get. It would be unmanageable. Just tag your question appropriately, give as much information in the question as you can, and trust that *someone* knowledgeable will come along and answer it.

Comment: It's more than poor form; doing this consistently will earn you a warning, continuing to do it will earn you a suspension.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I asked then. If I sought him out through more acceptable means (I think I could reach him through some MediaWiki help channel), would it be ok then to point him towards my SO question?

Comment: @LordFarquaad - You should look up any instructions/policies the MediaWiki team has on requesting help. I can't recall which product it was now but someone who worked on it got *extremely* angry that someone posted a question on both their help forum and on Stack Overflow. They may want you to only ask on their forum if you seek help there.

Comment: @BSMP Thanks, I'll investigate. I do have to ask though, was that person justified in being angry? Obviously, I'd understand if the user said something to the effect of, "no, just answer it on SO, not your forum." Barring that though, I'm guessing they wanted their help forum to be the place to go for questions, and since I'm using MediaWiki's service, I'll do that if they want, but it doesn't seem like they get to say you simply can't ask on other forums.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I can't recall the specifics of why it bothered them but I do remember that it was the fact that they asked in *both* places that upset them. I think they would have been OK with the question being on either site but not both.

Comment: @BSMP Ok thanks. If i get in touch with WikiMedia then I'll let them know I have a question up here as well and ask them if they mind.

Comment: @meagar why is that functionality even there if it is so bad?

Comment: @bin I'm not sure what you mean. That functionality *is not* here. You cannot ping arbitrary people, @ only notifies people who are already involved in a question. Pinging somebody directly who is not already part of the question  is not a feature the site supports, this question is about abusing the commenting system to work around this intentional limitation.

Comment: @meagar what I mean why does the comment system allow you to "reply" to a comment that has never been posted. So that functionality (notify a user who has not commented on a post about that post) is there. It would not be so hard to implement a system where @ notifies a person only if they posted a comment, I think (though I am not a developer).

Comment: @Bin It already does it as you describe (Well, in addition to people who commented, @ pings can also reach close voters and editors, but no one who hasn't interacted with the post). If I try to @ JonSkeet right now, he won't get any sort of notification, because he's never commented, edited, or close voted here.

Comment: @Will That doesn't change anything.

Comment: I haven't formulated my thought correctly. I get the distinct impression that the issue itself, not the question, is very low activity, and consequently, that expert rarely  gets the chance to be involved and would actually appreciate getting pinged. So that's why I think this answer doesn't apply.